# add text line in XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple XML file

```
 <Config new="Y" >
   <schema_path value="/var/tmp/sh.xsd"/>
   <collection name="new" >        
       <unit-list>
         <Instance active="Y" unit_type="xp" unit_name="table"/>
       </unit-list>
   </collection>
</Config>
```

I'd like to instert a new element `Instance` into xml in `unit-list`

```
<Instance active="N" unit_type="linux" unit_name="door" />
```

How to do it ?

Comment: Thank you , your xsl is working perfectly! In addition I'd like to fix two issues : #1. I have a comment at the end of xml file , this comment doesn't appear in mew output.xml.How to fix ? #2 small cosmetic issue : after adding a new line </unit-list> appear in same line with inserted line .Could it be fixed ? and last : could I ask for comment in 2-3 sentences how your script works. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This copies everything from the input XML and adds the `Instance` at the end of `unit-list`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="unit-list">
        <unit-list>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
            <Instance active="N" unit_type="linux" unit_name="door" />
        </unit-list>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*|text()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*|text()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you , your xsl is working perfectly! In addition I'd like to fix two issues : #1. I have a comment at the end of xml file , this comment doesn't appear in mew output.xml.How to fix ?  #2 small cosmetic issue : after adding a new line </unit-list> appear in same line with inserted line .Could it be fixed ? and last : could I ask for comment in 2-3 sentences how your script works. Thanks in advance !